# Aptana Terminal - PHP in CLI

Tags: php, windows, aptana, command-line-interface

At the start I was trying to run php commands for Symfony in wondows cmd.exe

*After a while i gave up.*

Since I use Aptana, I tried to figure out how to do commands like

`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

which is for Symfony2. But I cannot figure out of this is possible or not?

Since the Terminal in Aptana is Unix-style (looks like it anyway) I'd prefer doing php commands in Aptana Terminal

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To work you must have set in the PATH environment variable on your system the route to php, for example `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\`, be sure to place the last `\`.

If you have open Aptana, restart it. After this you can try running in the terminal  echo $ PATH,  in the output list should contain the path to PHP that just entered.

To test the configuration, run `php -version`, if the output is the version of php installed, simply position yourself in the symfony directory and run `php app / console`.